# Assigning integer to an enum using macro in C

Tags: c, optimization, enums, macros, coverity

I am working on a big project in which I need to use a generic macro to assign my values from a big payload. the values may be int, uint, bool or enum.
all other macros are working fine only for the enum I need help with.
Consider this piece of code as something I want to achieve.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum reasons { REASON1 = 1, REASON2 = 2, MAX_REASON = 3 };

#define SET_ENUM(dest, data) dest = data;

int main(void)
{
        int a = 2;
        enum reasons rs; 
        SET_ENUM(rs, a); 

        printf("REASON is -> %d\n", rs);
        return 0;
}
```

Here it works everything fine but in my Coverity run it shows

> Event mixed_enum_type:    enumerated type mixed with another type

I want to typecast the data to the dest but need to do it from the macro.
Any suggestions?

Comment: simply cast both to `int`. Remove `;` and even better wrap it into `do {} while(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a three-arg SET_ENUM, specifying the type:

```
#define SET_ENUM(dest, type, data) dest = (enum type) data
...
SET_ENUM(rs, reasons, a);
```

Or with certain compilers (gcc) you could use the `typeof` keyword:

```
#define SET_ENUM(dest, data) dest = (typeof(dest)) data
...
SET_ENUM(rs, a);
```

The `typeof` keyword is currently a non-standard extension, it seems to be planned for the C23 standard.

Comment: all your typecasts simple convert from `int` to `int`. Enum in C is just an syntactic sugar

Comment: the cast is just to inform the compiler, don't see any harm in that.

Comment: @0___________ sure, they don't add any meaning; I think the point of OP's question was to get rid of some coverity complaints

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I have 3 different types of enum and need to use the same macro.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor will replace `SET_ENUM(rs, a)`  with `rs = a`.

So you'll need to add the cast so that it is replaced by `rs = (reasons)a`.

If you are only setting that enum you could just define the macro as:

```c
#define SET_ENUM(dest, data) dest = (reasons)data;
```

If you want it to be for other enums, I'm afraid you'll have to add the enum as parameter to the macro:

```c
#define SET_ENUM(dest, data, T) dest = (T)data;
```

And then call it like this:

```c
SET_ENUM(rs, a, reason);
```

Comment: a very bad macro `if(x) SET_ENUM(a,b,c); else printf("Error");` will not compile

Comment: can you say why (if `c` is  an enum?) and how you would fix it? Also, it's just an example developing over what the OP already had.

Comment: This macro isn't thought to be perfect, just the simplest way, with minimal changes to what the OP asked, so that it works with correct params obviously.